# Javascript not working in ExactTarget Landing Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, dataextensions, landing-page

I am using a simple JavaScript to receive a row from [Data Extension Server-Side JavaScript Functions](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/) in ExactTarget and display the retrieved row on  Landing Page . As below

```
<script runat="server">  Platform.Load("core", "1");
var birthdayDE = DataExtension.Init("birthdayDE");
var filter = {
    Property: "EmailAddress",
    SimpleOperator: "equals",
    Value: "abc@gmail.com"
};
var data = birthdayDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter);
if (data.length > 0) {
    Write("<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='3' style='border-collapse:collapse;>");
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        var d = data[i];
        Write("<tr>");
        for (var key in d) {
            Write("<td>" + d[key] + "</td>");
        }
        Write("</tr>");
    }
    Write("</table>");} </script>
```

Somehow it does not show me any results nor give any errors.

Comment: Not entirely clear on how this relates to salesforce?

Comment: @Eric..I am trying to use "Data Extension Server-Side JavaScript Function" Retrieve(filter, QueryAllAccounts) and display the retrieved row on the landing page.

Comment: are you seeing any javascript errors within your browsers console?

Comment: No it is not giving me any kind of error.

Comment: What is the value of data.length?

Comment: The data.length value is 2 .

Comment: Is 'BirthdayDE' the name or external key of your data extension?

Comment: yes, I have the data extension name and external key both equal to BirthdayDE

Comment: Have you tried just harcoding the field names. so d.fieldname1 etc to see if that works.

Comment: I tried that too. It still does not give me anything. It looks like if use any of JavaScript with related to Data extension it does not give me result. I tires changing the  data extension  names and filter-flags too.

Comment: Could you change  for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++)  to  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  ?  This array as written will go out of bounds.

Comment: @Timothy...Thanks a lot your suggestion.Still no luck. Does not show any results nor error.

Comment: What about the opening and closing script tags?  Is there a row with abc@gmail.com as the EmailAddress in BirthdayDE?

Comment: Yes, I have opening and closing tags and the DE  BirthdayDE does have row with abc@gmail.com as the EmailAddress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a single quote at the end of the style attribute in your table tag.

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");
    var birthdayDE = DataExtension.Init("birthdayDE");
    var filter = {
        Property: "EmailAddress",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: "abc@gmail.com"
    };
    var data = birthdayDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter);
    Write("<br>data.length: " + data.length);

    if (data.length > 0) {

        Write("<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='3' style='border-collapse:collapse;'>");
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {

            var d = data[i];
            Write("<tr>");
            for (var i in d) {
                Write("<td>" + d[i] + "</td>");
            }
            Write("</tr>");
        }
        Write("</table>");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks...I think it was missed while copying the code. Though I have that in my original code.